# Updated to 2.93.7 cant export to fbx

Tags: export, .fbx

[image: blender fbx error]

I have updated blender through steam to latest LTS version 2.93.7.
Since then I cant export files as .fbx, no matter which scene I try to export I receive same error. I tried to change settings in .fbx exporter but still same error. Any solution or just downgrade?

Comment: I suspect this might be a bug instead of some problem to be solved with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Steam update missed the a file named `encode_bin.py`

In your Blender application folder find this path

```
D:\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\
```

This is the missing file
[`encode_bin.py`](https://code.it4i.cz/blender/blender-addons/-/blob/7fd30539c69ce4aa3363e0d7c5e00ff4ca13886b/io_scene_fbx/encode_bin.py)

Download it and put it on the path above